# How to use the ORMLite query builder to get the total records in a table

Tags: android, ormlite, query-builder

Similar to

```
select count(*) from tablename;
```

what should be query in ORMLITE

i tried something like

```
int total = dao.queryBuilder().("select count(*)");
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

> How to use the ORMLite query builder to get the total records in a table

[ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) has a [`Dao.countOf()`](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#countOf%28%29) method that returns the total number of rows in a table:

```
long numRows = dao.countOf();
```

You can also count the [number of rows in a custom query](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/Where.html#countOf()) by calling the `countOf()` method on the `Where` or `QueryBuilder` object.

```
// count the number of lines in this custom query
long numRows = dao.queryBuilder().where().eq("name", "Joe Smith").countOf();
```

Comment: countOf() will return long value not int

Comment: Thanks @KJEjava48.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

for package 5: you can use `countOf()`

From the docs:

> Returns the value returned from a SELECT COUNT(*) query which is the number of rows in the table. Depending on the database and the size of the table, this could be expensive.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with ormlite. I just searched.What about: dao.queryBuilder().countOf();

Comment: Did it work ? if so, please help me,yourself and the community by accepting this as the right answer