# ORMLite groupByRaw and groupBy issue on android SQLite db

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have a SQLite table *content* with following columns:

```
-----------------------------------------------
|id|book_name|chapter_nr|verse_nr|word_nr|word|
-----------------------------------------------
```

the sql query

```
select count(*) from content where book_name = 'John'
group by book_name, chapter_nr
```

in [DB Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) returns 21 rows (which is the count of chapters)

the equivalent with ORMLite android:

```
long count = getHelper().getWordDao().queryBuilder()
                        .groupByRaw("book_name, chapter_nr")
                        .where()
                        .eq("book_name", book_name)
                        .countOf();
```

returns 828 rows (which is the count of *verse numbers*)

as far as I know the above code is translated to:

```
select count(*) from content
where book_name = 'John'
group by book_name, chapter_nr
```

result of this in DB Browser:

```
   | count(*)
------------
 1 | 828
 2 | 430
 3 | 653
...
 21| 542
---------
21 Rows returned from: select count(*)...
```

so it seems to me that ORMLite returns the first row of the query as the result of `countOf()`.

I've searched stackoverflow and google a lot. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260781/how-to-use-the-ormlite-query-builder-to-get-the-total-records-in-a-table) (and more interestingly the answer)

> You can also count the number of rows in a custom query by calling the > countOf() method on the Where or QueryBuilder object.
>
> // count the number of lines in this custom query
>   int numRows = dao.queryBuilder().where().eq("name", "Joe Smith").countOf();

this is (correct me if I'm wrong) exactly what I'm doing, but somehow I just get the wrong number of rows.

So... either I'm doing something wrong here or `countOf()` is not working the way it is supposed to.

Note: It's the same with `groupBy` instead of `groupByRaw` (according to ORMLite documentation joining groupBy's should work)

```
...
.groupBy("book_name")
.groupBy("chapter_nr")
.where(...)
.countOf()
```

**EDIT**: `getWordDao` returns from class `Word`:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "content")
public class Word { ... }
```

Comment: are you sure you using correct DAO `getWordDao()` and not `getContentDao()`?

Comment: yes... should have posted Dao... but: class `Word` has the attribute `@DatabaseTable(tableName = "content")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> returns 828 rows (which is the count of verse numbers)

This seems to be a limitation of the `QueryBuilder.countOf()` mechanism.  It is expecting a single value and does not understand the addition of `GROUP BY` to the count query.  You can tell that it doesn't because that method returns a single `long`.

If you want to extract the counts for each of the groups it looks like you will need to do a [raw query check out the docs](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries).

Comment: thanks for your answer... i see your point, but what's strange anyhow is that the statement generated by the `QueryBuilder` is correct (in terms of SQL... it is translated correctly). i just don't understand why a realtively simple query, which is obviously translated to SQL in a right way, is processed in a wrong way... or at least not as expected.

Comment: The problem is that ORMLite is asking then for a single integer result.  It gets the first number from the results and ignores all of the rest @stefankmitph.

Comment: still don't understand why it is supposed to work to this way (obviously by design). but you're the man who's working on it and i find your answer helpful, so i'm gonna accept it. by the way... just wanted to say that OrmLite is a great tool and helped me to save a lot of time and work. thanks for it!